# Arrow in text mode

Tags: symbols, arrows

Is there a way to write the equivalent of `\rightarrow` in text mode?

I tried `→` but it threw an error, and the math arrow complained about bad environment.

It doesn't need to be exactly the same arrow, I just want to write something like "A → B" as in A points to B.

Comment: You can use `A$\,\to\,$B`

Comment: Why not `$\rightarrow$`?

Comment: I hoped there's a cleaner way than making a math context just for the one arrow, but yeah that'll do the trick as well.

Comment: @MightyPork there's a text-mode option. See my answer below.

Comment: @c.p. Not here, they are names of nodes, not math related. If they were points, yeah.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use something like `A$\,\to\,$B` or `A\textrightarrow B` (in text mode) from the `textcomp` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}


A$\,\to\,$B

A\textrightarrow B

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want space around the arrow, use this instead: `A \textrightarrow{} B`

Comment: BTW: List of all available symbols in [`textcomp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package is available [here](http://gcp.fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/_media/integrantes:psantamaria:latex:textcomp.pdf). Unfortunately there is no `\textleftrightarrow` (equivalent of [`\leftrightarrow`](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) that is available in math mode).

Answer (score 5):

With `fontspec`, you can simply paste the Unicode glyphs for arrows after selecting any font that contains them, or use commands such as `\char"2194` or `\symbol`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `A \verb|->| B`.

To me this is the simplest and most flexible solution, and renders nicely too (sure, it does not look like the right arrow in math mode but for many purposes it might be enough). You can control spacing very easily inside the verbatim. For instance, more spacing would be `A \verb| -> | B`. Both are shown below.

[image]