# How to have an arrow in textual environment?

Tags: fonts, arrows

I tried unsuccessfully `\rightarrow`, `\textrightarrow`, `\to{}`, `\rightarrow{}`. 
I would like to have an arrow without Math environment.

How can you have an arrow in an textual environment?

Comment: How about inline math, like `$\rightarrow$`?

Comment: Try this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229290/85494

Comment: In XeTeX `→` or `\char"2192` should just work, I guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible to use arrows in non-math style using the `textcomp` package. It defines some arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\textleftarrow

\textrightarrow

\textdownarrow

\textuparrow

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Here is some addition with unicode support within (pdf)latex:
Some (but not yet all) unicode characters can be just copied or entered with some code into the `.tex` document and compiled, if `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is used. (The symbol → can be typed directly or copied from a character table application (Windows Symbol map) or KCharSelect on KDE on Linux etc., for example)

However, not any copied or entered character is yet recognized. With `\newunicodechar` from Enrico Gregorio's (egreg!!!) package `newunicodechar` it's possible to prepare the document to use the direct symbol. See the example for it's usage.

The unicode characters usually have a symbolic representation (the unicode):  → has the code U+2192

The way, how unicode characters can be typed directly depends on the operating system and editors, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>2192</kbd> is a good guess (at least it works for Firefox)

*A former version used `ucs` and `\unichar` -- thanks to some notes by egreg, I dropped this and revised the example*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\showverb}[1]{%
  \texttt{\textbackslash#1} & \csname #1\endcsname  \tabularnewline
}

\newunicodechar{⇐}{\ensuremath{\Leftarrow}}
\newunicodechar{⇑}{\ensuremath{\Uparrow}}
\newunicodechar{⇒}{\ensuremath{\Rightarrow}}
\newunicodechar{⇓}{\ensuremath{\Downarrow}}
\newunicodechar{↦}{\ensuremath{\mapsto}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Macro & Output \tabularnewline
\midrule[2pt]
  \showverb{textleftarrow}
  \showverb{textuparrow}
  \showverb{textdownarrow} 
  \showverb{textuparrow}
\midrule[2pt]
& \tabularnewline
Unicode character &  output \tabularnewline
\midrule[2pt]
2190 & ← \tabularnewline
2191 & ↑ \tabularnewline
2192 & → \tabularnewline
2193 & ↓ \tabularnewline
21D0 & ⇐ \tabularnewline
21D1 & ⇑ \tabularnewline
21D2 & ⇒ \tabularnewline
21D3 & ⇓ \tabularnewline
21A6 & ↦
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can create a command:

`\newcommand{\textarrow}{$\rightarrow$}`

You will use the math mode but without using math delimiters in fact.