# Arrows, edges and vertices

Tags: arrows, graphs, edge

For my bachelor thesis I would like to create the following arrows, or more precise orientated subgraphs, so far I was not able to create them. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: Please show us a minimal working example showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In which context would you use these arrows?

Comment: Okay, I think I found to the solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402727/combining-arrow-symbols-in-text . The only thing that is missing is the point, representing the vertice "between" the arrows. @Bernard, what do you mean with context?

Comment: Well , in a display or inline math formula, or as an illustration within pure text?

Comment: Inline math formula and within pure text.